# mysql.h is missing . OS X 10.10.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, osx-yosemite, mysql2

Here is my [error log](http://pastebin.com/0RA329iD). I've been trying to do a `bundle install` and it asked me install mysql2. I've tried most of the things on stackoverflow and nothing seems to work for me.

I did the following

`gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'`, no luck.

`gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/bin/mysql`

`gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.19/bin/mysql_config`

Tried removing/changing the cflags and cxxflags in mysql_config.

None of the above attempts worked.

Anyone has a different solution for this problem? what else should I try ?

I did `brew install mysql` and its in `/usr/local/bin/mysql`,

Okay I think it has got something to do with it not being able to find the MySql header files. I'm not able to find the MySQL development files installed.

Tried doing a `which mysql-devel` and it gives `mysql-devel not found`. How do I install this? brew install does not work in this case.

Comment: mysql_config itself is failing to run. Not sure why that would be. You might get a more explicit failure message running it by hand (e.g. `mysql_config --include`)

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to use mysql2 as the database for Ruby on Rails? If so maybe the gem you need is "activerecord-mysql2-adapter".

Comment: No, I'm looking for the mysql2 gem specifically. It is the one used in prod for our project.